# Unable to query an API using django forms

Tags: python, django, api

I'm trying to query an API using django form and running into difficulty querying the API from the form on the frontend. I have a python script with hard coded values that when ran in the terminal, will successfully query the API I'm using.

**Script**

```
    import requests
    import urllib.request as urllib2
    import json

    url = "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant?"

    body = {
      "query": "query",
      'query': "apple",

    }

    headers = {
        'x-app-id': "ff0ccea8",
        'x-app-key': "605660a17994344157a78f518a111eda",
        'x-remote-user-id': "7a43c5ba-50e7-44fb-b2b4-bbd1b7d22632",

    }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, params=body, headers=headers)

    print(response.json()['common'])
```

At the moment I'm trying to pass the 'food' variable from the form to the end of the URL, and then query that API using the URL to return the food calories count from 'Nutritionix API.' The problem is that the food variable is going to the end of the URL in the browser but its not querying the API. 
I'm fairly sure I'm doing it wrong and should be using python request BODY, like in the example above where i hard-code apple into the query, because this returns what i want into my terminal.

**form.py**

```
class NutritionForm(forms.Form):
    food = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    # nf_calories = forms.DecimalField()

    def search(self):
        result = {}
        food = self.cleaned_data['food']
        endpoint = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search?{item_id}'
        url = endpoint.format(item_id=food)
        headers = {'app_id': settings.NUTRITIONIX_APP_ID, 'app_key': settings.NUTRITIONIX_APP_KEY}
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        if response.status_code == 200: #SUCCESS
            result = response.json()
            result['success'] = True
        else:
            result['success'] = False
            if response.status_code == 404:
                result['message'] = 'No entry found for "%s"' % food
            else:
                result['message'] = 'The Nutritionix API is not available at the moment. Please try again later.'
        return result
```

Is there a way to connect django forms to this `Script` above that will allow users to query the API from a web-page. 
Any advice or documentation would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

When I query the API I'm passing from the form to my 'views.py' class and, the URL in the browser is getting returned,

```
def nutritionix(request):
    search_result = {}
    if 'food' in request.GET:
        form = NutritionForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            search_result = form.search()
    else:
        form = NutritionForm()
    //The following URL is returned into the browser
    //For example http://127.0.0.1:8000/nutrition/food/?food=orange
    return render(request, 'nutrition/nutrition.html', {'form': form, 'search_results': search_result})
```

Im trying to pass the results from the API query to the front end like so,

```
{% block content %}
  <h2>Nutritionix API</h2>

  <form method="get">
{#      {% csrf_token %}#}
      {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do correctly (query a third party API and return a value to the user without storing the data in your database), you might be better served using JavaScript on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Your standalone script uses the endpoint "/v2/search/instant", but your Django version has just "/v2/search". Also, the script has querystring parameters "query=whatever", but in Django you just use "whatever".

I don't know why you don't do the same thing as in your script:

```
url = 'https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/instant'
body = {'query': food}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=body)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to do what you suggested but it didn't work. Could it be an issue with how i handle the data after the query is made. I've updated the question to include that code.